# How to make QTableView selection not affect QIcons/QPixmaps set by DecorationRole?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm using PyQt6 and have a custom QTableView and a custom QTableModel. The model's data method looks like this:

```
    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: Qt.ItemDataRole = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole:
            if not index.column():
                # print(index.row())
                artwork_pixmap = self._tracks[index.row()].artwork_pixmap
                artwork_pixmap = artwork_pixmap if artwork_pixmap else QPixmap(f"icons/album.png")
                icon = QIcon(artwork_pixmap)
                return icon
```

_tracks is a list containing custom objects which have the pixmap I want to display, and if they don't then I just display default pixmap from image album.png. That all works fine, the QIcons get displayed in the first column. But once I select the row it also makes the QIcon blueish, which isn't what I want. And it makes it blueish regardless of the selection color set in the stylesheet of my view. Even if I set it's focus policy to NoFocus, it doesn't select anything on click but it still makes the QIcon in the row I clicked in turn blueish. Is there any way to prevent this?

Here is the example, the first row is the one I clicked in, the background color hasn't change because of NoFocus, but the QIcon became blueish in comparison to it's normal color.

[image: example]

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own item delegate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QIcon automatically creates alternate versions of the given pixmap for `Disabled` and `Selected` [icon modes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#Mode-enum), the first is a grayed out version of the pixmap, the second overlays a layer based on the palette `Highlight` role.

To override those icons, just explicitly set the pixmap for the desired state with [`addPixmap()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#addPixmap):

```py
    artwork_pixmap = self._tracks[index.row()].artwork_pixmap
    if not artwork_pixmap:
        artwork_pixmap = QPixmap("icons/album.png")
    icon = QIcon(artwork_pixmap)
    icon.addPixmap(artwork_pixmap, QtGui.QIcon.Selected)
    return icon
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Although I managed to do it by making my own item delegate, as @G.M. suggested, this is much simpler solution. In any case, the good thing is that by writing my own delegate I also managed to accidentally avoid the dotted line around the selected item.